# Swift - UITableViewCell height according to UITextView layout constraint

Tags: ios, swift

In my table view cell are 3 objects; an imageview, label and a textview.

This is how I set up my textView and its constraints:

```
textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
textView.textColor = UIColor.blue
textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:15.0)
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
textView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

**note that `self` is a `UIView` that contains the textView. The table view cell's content view will contain this `UIView`

```
self.addConstraints([
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -10.0),
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 20.0)
            ])
```

I made `isScrollEnabled = false` so that the textView's height is calculated according to its content

For my UITableView I did this:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

With the above code my tableviewcell does not show the correct height. I believe its because my textview height constraint is giving the tableviewcell content view a wrong height.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Setting `isScrollEnabled = false` will not affect calculating textView's height

Comment: @alexburtnik that and heightAnchor does change the textView according to its height. Sorry if my explanation was unclear

Comment: @alexburtnik I was able to change the textView's height according to content but still no luck changing table view cell's height

Answer (score 0):

1. Setting `isScrollEnabled = false` will not affect calculating textView's height.
2. In order to resize cell according to textView's content you should add **bottom(=)** constraint to your `textView` in addition to **top(=)** and ***optional* height(>=)**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `tableView(heightForRowAt:)` delegate method?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return textView.frame.height // Assuming you have a reference to the textview
}
```

Comment: @imstillalive lol nice unnecessary and completely wrong comment.